# Detecting the language a question is written in

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

It would be great if the system could detect the language of a question, and pop up a little notice:

> Please note that this site is in English only
>
> Your question will be flagged for moderator attention. Please help the editors by spelling carefully, so that they can use a translation program. Thank you.

(and in their respective langauge)

Then, the system should automatically flag the question with "translation needed".

All of this should be possible using the google translation api (which I know nothing about, so I might be wrong).

What do we think? Is that something that could work?

---

At the moment, people are quite quick to translate questions, but they're often stumped by complicated grammar (i.e. Google translate is).

Comment: It would be great to have this feature, so loco teams can follow questions written in their language, just to make use of the stunning features on this site. Forums are already aged and requires *not-simple* registration procedure...
also: [how-to-get-notified-about-questions-in-specific-language](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2295/how-to-get-notified-about-questions-in-specific-language-on-askubuntu-com)

Answer (score 1):

How often does this happen?

How many questions per day are submitted in a language other than English?

This would be a fair bit of work.

Comment: When I wrote this question, you could send some text to goolge and it would [detect the language](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/getting_started.html#detectResult) easy as pie, but that's since been deprecated. I'd say we get about one of these questions per week, if that.