# How to get notified about questions in specific language on askubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion

Currently, Our LoCo is receiving all questions from Ubuntu users on FB group, this has many disadvantages as it wasn't made for it mainly. We need to move it to Ask Ubuntu, but **How can an individual/group of people get notified if some question is asked in a specific language?**. If it's asked in English it won't be a problem, as English speaking supports are many.

Comment: You might want to ask on meta, but my suggestion might be to use tags.

Comment: Currently [Ask Ubuntu doesn't support any languages other than English](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1506/what-to-do-with-non-english-questions-or-answers)

Comment: Have any idea, when this feature might be implemented?
Thanks

Comment: At this time there is not short or long term plan for this. I think discussions about this may start in the next 3-6 months

Comment: We do not need language tags. Please do not add language specific tags.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Ok, no problem.

Comment: See also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1602/detecting-the-language-a-question-is-written-in